# AWS Neptune: Custom vertex id in javascript

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'd like to specify my own vertex id's. According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html) they are supported like so

`g.addV().property(id, 'customid')`

with no quotes around `id`. This causes JS to parse it as a variable, and it fails (undefined variable). Where do I import `id`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try adding this to the code before you call the addV.

```
const { t: { id } } = gremlin.process;
```

That will correctly import id from gremlin.process for you.

Hope this help,
Kelvin

Comment: Thanks. Is there a good reference for these imports? For example, I'm now trying to find where to import the cardinality variable `single`.

Comment: `const { cardinality: { single } } = gremlin.process;` Found it by inspecting the exports in traversal.js here https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-javascript/src/main/javascript/gremlin-javascript/lib/process/traversal.js.

Comment: Yes,to be honest I usually refer to the source code or dump gremlin.process using a console.log!  I have it on my todo list to add coverage of the other GLVs to Practical Gremlin. Just need to find the time!

Comment: Whoa this is a great resource! Linking here for others: http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html